# Display hostname in SDDM QML Login Screen

Tags: qml, themes, kde-plasma

I am trying to get my system to display the hostname in the login screen. I am using SDDM and have edited the associated QML files to display static text where I want it. However, I have found in the SDDM wiki on GitHub that there is a proxy object named *sddm* that has a hostname property.

How do I get the object (I am assuming it is *sddm.hostname*) to display using QML?

here is the code I tried

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

import org.kde.plasma.core 2.0
import org.kde.plasma.components 2.0
import org.kde.plasma.extras 2.0

ColumnLayout {
  Label {
    text: sddm.hostname
    font.pointSize: 14
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
  }
}
```

but it looks like 'text:' only accepts strings and I need it to accept sddh.hostname

thanks
-L

Comment: Please post you code, links etc.

Comment: Sorry. The SDDM GitHub link I was referring to is <https://github.com/sddm/sddm/wiki/Theming#proxy-object>. I am looking for the code to use in the qml file to display the hostname either via the sddm proxy object or some other way.

Comment: Ok, as I see it's pretty clear - `We provide a proxy object, called as sddm to the themes as a context property.`

Comment: I added the code to the original question - I could not figure out how to get it into the comments...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution from a theme file on GitHub [https://github.com/bchretien/sddm-futuristic-theme/blob/master/futuristic/Main.qml] - it looks like I have a naming error. When I use *text: sddm.hostName* it works on the login. The code that works is

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

import org.kde.plasma.core 2.0
import org.kde.plasma.components 2.0
import org.kde.plasma.extras 2.0

ColumnLayout {
  Label {
    text: sddm.hostName
    font.pointSize: 14
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
  }
}
```

Now I just need to figure out why it is not working on the lock screen, but that may be the topic of another question!